# Компиляция с BOOST

Tags: boost, компиляция, c++

Установил себе C++Builder XE в надежде овладеть BOOST'ом (она прилагается к дистрибутиву).
Пытаюсь откомпилировать пример из дистрибутива же:

```
// simple_example_1.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<string>
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;

int main(){
   string s = "This is,  a test";
   tokenizer<> tok(s);
   for(tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg)
       cout << *beg << "\n";
}
```

Программа должна разрезать строку по пробелам.

При компиляции открывается файл tuple.hpp
и на строках:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
```

показывают ошибку, типа на могу открыть файл по этим путям. Эти пути, действительно, отсутствуют. Может быть какого-то макроса в исходнике не хватает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define BOOST_TR1_USE_OLD_TUPLE` перед инклудами `boost'a`.

Comment: Спасибо, ни секунды не сомневался в Вашей компетнтности!